# Trap focus error when closging a MUI dialog

Tags: material-ui, dialog

Used the code below to display a dialog, then try to close the dialog
Hi I've created a dialog that displays upon the app starting up. But whenever I try to close it it gives the following error.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
    at HTMLDocument.contain (FocusTrap.js:225:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (FocusTrap.js:225:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (FocusTrap.js:225:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (FocusTrap.js:225:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (FocusTrap.js:225:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (FocusTrap.js:225:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (FocusTrap.js:225:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (FocusTrap.js:225:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (FocusTrap.js:225:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (FocusTrap.js:225:1)
```

then tried using the example from MUI but that too gives an error in my code base but not on MUI. What am I doing wrong? Here's the code:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { compose, withProps } from 'recompose';
import { withErrorBoundary } from 'react-error-boundary';
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { PageNotFoundView } from './PageNotFoundView';
import SplashPage from './SplashPage';
import LoadingPanel from './LoadingPanel';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemAvatar from '@mui/material/ListItemAvatar';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import PersonIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Person';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { blue } from '@mui/material/colors';



let Apps = [];
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {

  const papabearAppRouter = require('papabear/AppRouter');
  const gamemasterAppRouter = require('gamemaster/AppRouter');
  const papabearconstants = require('papabearconstants');
  const gamemasterconstants = require('gamemasterconstants');

  Apps = [
    {
      Name: papabearconstants.default.NAME,
      Component: papabearAppRouter.default,
    },
    {
      Name: gamemasterconstants.default.NAME,
      Component: gamemasterAppRouter.default,
    }
  ];
}

const enhance = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? compose(
    Component => withErrorBoundary(
      Component,
      withProps(() => ({
        loading: false,
        logoText: (
          <span>INSERT A COIN TO CONTINUE</span>
        ),
        statusText: null,
        children: (
          <div>
            We have encountered an error, please refresh the page and try again.
            <hr />
            Still hitting the same error?&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a className="internalLink" href="">
              <span className="fa fa-envelope" role="img" aria-label="e-mail" />
              {' '}
              Tell us about it
            </a>
          </div>
        ),
      }))(LoadingPanel),
    ),
  )
  // In development, just let it fly
  : compose();
const emails = ['username@gmail.com', 'user02@gmail.com'];

function ComplianceDialog(props) {
  const { onClose, selectedValue, open } = props;

  const handleClose = () => {
    onClose(selectedValue);
  };

  const handleListItemClick = (value) => {
    onClose(value);
  };

  return (
    <Dialog onClose={handleClose} open={open}>
      <DialogTitle>Set backup account</DialogTitle>


      <DialogContent>
        <List sx={{ pt: 0 }}>
          {emails.map((email) => (
            <ListItem disableGutters key={email}>
              <ListItemButton onClick={() => handleListItemClick(email)}>
                <ListItemAvatar>
                  <Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: blue[100], color: blue[600] }}>
                    <PersonIcon />
                  </Avatar>
                </ListItemAvatar>
                <ListItemText primary={email} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
          <ListItem disableGutters>
            <ListItemButton
              autoFocus
              onClick={() => handleListItemClick('addAccount')}
            >
              <ListItemAvatar>
                <Avatar>
                  <AddIcon />
                </Avatar>
              </ListItemAvatar>
              <ListItemText primary="Add account" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}


ComplianceDialog.propTypes = {
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  selectedValue: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};



const AppRouter = (props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(emails[1]);


  const handleClose = (value) => {
    setOpen(false);
    setSelectedValue(value);
  };


  const prefix = "test"

 

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography variant="subtitle1" component="div">
        Selected: {selectedValue}
      </Typography>
      <ComplianceDialog
        selectedValue={selectedValue}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose} />
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${prefix}/{PATHS.HOME}`} render={() => <Redirect to={prefix} />} />
        <Route exact path={prefix} component={SplashPage} />

        {Apps.map((app, index) => {
          return <Route key={index} path={`${prefix}/${app.Name}`} component={app.Component} />;
        })
        }

        { /* catch-all route for anything else we have missed */}
        <Route path={`${prefix}`} component={PageNotFoundView} />

      </Switch>


    </div>
  );

};

export default enhance(AppRouter);
```

The code above with the dialog reflects using the simple dialog from the MUI Examples from what I can find out on line this error is caused by trying to display muiltple dialogs but this as you can see I'm only creating 1
Current behavior

When I close the dialog I have to click multiple times before it closes. I check the console log and there are numerous trapfocus errors
Expected behavior

The dialog should close after clicking only 1 time and no trapfocus errors.
Context

I'm trying to open a dialog when the app opens to display information to the users. This is causing confusion and annoyances to the users.

Environment:

```
System:
    OS: Linux 3.10 CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.20.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 7.24.2 - ~/node_modules/.bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 118.0.5993.117
  npmPackages:
    @emotion/react: latest => 11.11.1 
    @emotion/styled: latest => 11.11.0 
    @mui/base:  5.0.0-beta.20 
    @mui/core-downloads-tracker:  5.14.14 
    @mui/envinfo: ^2.0.12 => 2.0.12 
    @mui/icons-material: ^5.14.14 => 5.14.14 
    @mui/lab: ^5.0.0-alpha.149 => 5.0.0-alpha.149 
    @mui/material: ^5.14.14 => 5.14.14 
    @mui/private-theming:  5.14.14 
    @mui/styled-engine:  5.14.14 
    @mui/styles: ^5.14.14 => 5.14.14 
    @mui/system:  5.14.14 
    @mui/types:  7.2.6 
    @mui/utils:  5.14.14 
    @mui/x-data-grid: ^6.16.2 => 6.16.2 
    @mui/x-data-grid-generator: ^6.16.2 => 6.16.2 
    @mui/x-data-grid-premium: ^6.16.2 => 6.16.2 
    @mui/x-data-grid-pro:  6.16.2 
    @mui/x-license-pro:  6.10.2 
    @mui/x-tree-view:  6.0.0-alpha.1 
    @types/react:  17.0.66 
    react: ^18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
    react-dom: ^18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
    styled-components: ^5.3.10 => 5.3.11
```

Comment: In case you or others run into this. I had the same issue when two versions of mui were loading into the page at the same time. I needed to cleanup the multiple versions of @mui/base and @mui/material to get mine cleaned up.